# Generating multiple columns dynamically using loop in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I have to generate multiple columns dynamically in pyspark. I have written a similar code as below to accomplish the same.

```
sc = SparkContext()                                                          
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
cols = ['a','b','c']    

df = sqlContext.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", "|").csv("C:\\Users\\elkxsnk\\Desktop\\sample.csv")

for i in cols:
    df1 = df.withColumn(i,lit('hi'))
df1.show()
```

However I am missing out columns a and b in the final result. Please help.

Changed the code like below. its working now, but wanted to know if there is a better way of handling it.

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
cols_add = []
flg_first = 'Y'
df = sqlContext.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", "|").csv("C:\\Users\\elkxsnk\\Desktop\\sample.csv")
for i in cols:
    print('start'+str(df.columns))
    if flg_first == 'Y':
        df1 = df.withColumn(i,lit('hi'))
        cols_add.append(i)
        flg_first = 'N'
    else:enter code here
        df1 = df1.select(df.columns+cols_add).withColumn(i,lit('hi'))
        cols_add.append(i)
    print('end' + str(df1.columns))

df1.show()
```

Comment: inside your loop the left side is `df1` but the right side is `df`. So each iteration, you are overwriting the previous result. Do `df1 = df` *before* of your loop and change the loop to: `df1 = df1.withColumn(i,lit('hi'))`.

Comment: Sure. I have realized that. I changed the code like above(added) to achieve what i want however i feel there should be a better way. Please review and suggest.

Comment: A more compact notation using `functools.reduce` would be: `df1 = reduce(lambda d, i: d.withColumn(i, lit('hi')), cols, df)`, but this just hides the loop. Under the hood it should be the same execution plan.